# Using a realm outside of react components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I am using `@realm/react` in my react native application.
Unfortunately, the docs are not that great.

They offer a ContextProvider and hooks that you can use to access the realm but there is no possibility to access the realm from outside a component (e.g. some outside logic I call from a component).
I could go ahead and create my own realm and write my own context but that seems like swimming against the current.

Is there a realm-way of doing this? Create a realm, associate the realm context to that realm and use the realm outside of the react-world as well?

(I know, that I could pass the realm from the component to the functions but that means I have to drag it through multiple instances of function calls and that just feels wrong)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/js/latest/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, just create SingletonClass to hold Realm instance, in every function you need to use `Realm`, you must check if it == null before use.

Here is simple way to use it by Singleton class:

```
export default class RealmManager {

    static myInstance = null;

    _realm = null;


    /**
     * @returns {RealmManager}
     */
    static getInstance() {
        if (RealmManager.myInstance == null) {
            RealmManager.myInstance = new RealmManager();
        }

        return this.myInstance;
    }

    getRealm() {
        return this._realm;
    }

    setRealm(realm){
        this._realm = realm;
    }
}
```

Then in first class inside RealmContext, you get the realm instance inside `useEffect` then set to `RealmManager`, make sure it's not re-render while using app

Comment: This is a really complicated solution for just a variable you want to share. You could save the realm instance in an exported variable for the same effect without a whole class around it.

Comment: @Fuzzyma Generally speaking  opening and closing a realm has low overhead and is preferred over keeping a realm 'open' for the duration of the app - which is what would happen with an exported variable (Realm is thread bound). That being said, I am not sure this code will work as is; Realm needs a configuration and also needs to be instantiated - I don't think this code does either.

Comment: The react package that provides a realm context is doing the same thing. Only problem is, that grabbing the active instance ends up being rather unstable